# Thread 1: signal SIGABRT Swift Xcode

Tags: swift, xcode

It's happening on the "class" line, can't seem to figure out the issue.

```
@UIApplicationMain
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate {
```

Comment: It's certainly happening somewhere else, set the Exception Breakpoint to get the real line.

Comment: Only been with xCode for a few months, how would I go about doing that?

Comment: Press ⌘8, then click on the plus sign bottom left

Answer (score 0):

Even though Xcode crashes in the AppDelegate class declaration, the SIGABRT error is most likely not in that part of the code. As @vadian commented, an exception breakpoint can help you find the real problematic line.

But, from my experience, these errors usually show up due to some wrong manipulation of @IBOutlets. I suggest you check any recently changed storyboards and/or .xib views to check if your outlets are properly connected and initialized.

Some common mistakes are

- The name of an outlet was changed in the storyboard but not in the
  code, or vice versa.
- An element was removed from the storyboard but
  the outlet was not deleted from the class code.
- An unitiliazed outlet
  is being forcecasted (!), etc.

Comment: Thanks for the comment, but I tried looking for any issues with IBOutlets, code leading to the wrong/non-existent .xib or storyboards. I still get the same error in my App delegate. Is there any code I can drop here that would could possibly help solve the issue that you can look at?

Comment: When the app crashes, the console usually shows some helpful output indicating what caused the exception. Try pasting it here, it may display some extra information.